# smart-table Angular module unable to sort

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am unable to do a simple sort for my [Smart Table Angular module](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). Shouldn't I just be able to add `st-sort="propertyName"` to my `th`?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{color:'red'},{color:'blue'}];
}]);
```

Html:

```
<html ng-app="app"><body ng-controller="SomeController">
  <table st-table="items">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th st-sort="color">Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.color}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

If you click the `Colors` `th`, nothing happens and the data does not sort. What am I missing? Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/ganine/2/edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add a `smart-table` module dependency to you `app` module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['smart-table']);
```

See working [example](http://jsbin.com/fomefuxaqe/1/edit).

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the smart-table script and add the `'smart-table'` module reference to your `app` module definition.

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['smart-table']);
```

You can see my changes in jsbin - http://jsbin.com/bunokerife/3/edit