# Smart-Table "st-sort" not working

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using angular v1.3.15. I'm fetching data by hitting an api and passing it through the scope to the smart table like so

[image]

Here is the data format of the 'scope.rowCollection' as seen on the console

[image]

Data populates fine but When i'm trying to click on the table-header and sort it using st-sort method, the table values go blank clearly not sorting the column. Here is a view of my html snippet

[image]

Can you please tell me what exactly am i doing wrong. The moment i use my own data collection set(NOT hard coded) the whole table values go haywire.
I have a feeling its something to do with the variable names that i'm using on the angular end. 
Any help is much appreciated....Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Following your comment Nikhil. Use *st-safe-src* like so:

**HTML**

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th st-sort="firstName">First Name</th>
          <th st-sort="lastName">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
          <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, service) {
    $scope.displayedCollection = [];

    service.all.then(function(list) {
        $scope.rowCollection = list;
        $scope.displayedCollection = list;
    });
});
```

That's it.

Comment: This answer is helpful for me. Thank you !

Comment: Another common reason for non-sorting is described here and this one solved my problem of not beeing able to sort: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28773921/2580805

Answer (score 5):

If you are bringing in data asynchronously (from a remote database, restful endpoint, ajax call, etc) you must use the stSafeSrc attribute. You must use a seperate collection for both the base and safe collections or you may end up with an infinite loop.

Since I am getting data from restful service 
st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection"
solve my issue

Comment: Nice to have some explanation since the top answer lacks any!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is trying to sort on row.name in the way that you code it. Try the following to see if it works:

```
     st-sort="employee.name"
```

Comment: Hey Kay.. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that too but didn't seem to work. Apparently i believe as my data is loading asynchronously, i should have used ```st-safe-src``` attribute according to the smart-table doc [here](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#examples-section)